# External module available for libraries in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass, algebraic-data-types

This will be very unusual question, but I'm generating Haskell code in a very special way, so I know what I'm trying to do may sound as an anti-pattern.

Lets say:

1. we've got libraries `LA` and `LB`
2. library `LA` consist of module `A` and library `LB` consist of module `B`
3. each module defines `DataType` (respectively `DA` and `DB`)
4. we have got **somewhere** module `X`, which consist **only** of definition of `TypeClass` `TX`
5. both `DA` and `DB` are instances of `TX`

I'm generating `LA` and `LB` in separate steps and they do not know about each other, so the module `X` cannot be part of any of them. (`DA` and `DB` simply share common functions defined in `TX`).

I want to ask you if is it possible to have the module `X` separately from libraries `LA` and `LB`?

Do I have to make `X` separate library (`LX`) or there is a way to tell Haskell that `DA` and `DB` are simply instances of **the same** `TypeClass` `X`.

Making a separate library of `X` (which consists only of one `TypeClass` seems like an overkill to me, but in this situation, there could be no better solution).

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the separate library. If both `LA` and `LB` define a module `M` containing `X` then `"library-a" M.X` will not be equal to `"library-b" M.X` and you'll get import errors if you try to import them (vanilla Haskell doesn't do anything special to handle namespace clashes).

Comment: @JAbrahamson: Thank you :) I know that it will be not equal (I've tested it) and I was looking for maybe better way to handle this situation than making a separate library - but if its the only one I'll do it this way. 

Additional could you please tell me - when user `U1` generates library `TX` and user `U2` generates **the same** library `TX` are they compatible? I mean - if `U1` makes `LA` and `U2` makes `LB`, than could `U3` use (`LA`, `LB` and `LX` where `LX` is any generated `LX`)?

Comment: Ah, sorry, unfortunately this is the only way I know and what I tend to see in Hackage. I'm also not too certain about how compiled artifacts work with GHC.